# Mismatch in SQLAlchemy when using dates in filter

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a table called `Opinion` in PostgreSQL database that contains a couple of columns. However, the relevant ones are:

- `report_version_id`, represents an integer type
- `content_created_at`, represents a timestampz type
- `assigned`, represents a bool type

Let be this query:

```
select count(*) 
from opinion o 
where report_version_id = 14 
and assigned = true 
and date_trunc('day', content_created_at) = '2021-05-23';
```

using DBeaver client, I get a count: 374, but when using SQLAlchemy (v1.4.11) in a Python script (v3.7) I get another count, 372. This is the code used in Python:

```
return (session.query(Opinion).filter(func.date_trunc('day', Opinion.content_created_at) == date)
        .filter(Opinion.report_version_id == report_version_id,
                Opinion.assigned == True)
        .count())
```

I have played around and doing counts without using dates everything matches, so my guessing is 1) there is something I'm doing wrong and don't know, or 2) there is a bug in this version when dealing with dates in filter.

I'm completely sure I'm connected to the same database, and no transactions have been executed while connected from the 2 different sources (DBeaver client and Terminal in local from where I'm running the Python script).

Edit:

This is the query I get when compiling it:

```sql
SELECT opinion.report_version_id ...
FROM opinion 
WHERE date_trunc(%(date_trunc_1)s, opinion.content_created_at) = %(date_trunc_2)s 
AND opinion.report_version_id = %(report_version_id_1)s 
AND opinion.assigned = true
```

As per Anudeep suggested in his answer, I'm adding the literal query:

```sql
SELECT opinion.report_version_id ...
FROM opinion 
WHERE date_trunc('day', opinion.content_created_at) = '2021-05-23' 
AND opinion.report_version_id = 14 
AND opinion.assigned = true
```

I have also compared what I get using the DBeaver client and the script, and I seem to be getting more because there is is a difference in the timezone applied. Records that I'm getting are from the next day (2021-05-24) within 1 hour ahead.

## Answer

Check that time zone when connected is the same as the one when this data was inserted into the db. You can set this configuration like this:

```
creds = {
    "url": f"{DB_ENGINE}://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASS}@{DB_HOST}:{DB_PORT}/{DB_NAME}",
    "echo": False,
    "connect_args": {
        "options": "-c timezone=utc-1"
    }
}
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine or sqlalchemy.engine_from_config(creds, prefix=""))()
```

Comment: The SQL looks to be the same for both.  Are you sure that the parameters are the same for both queries?  Are you able to identify which rows form the difference, if you remove the `COUNT`s?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try printing the query with literal bound params and check if you are getting the correct values set in python query.

```
print(q.statement.compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}))
```